# On Cordova cli-8: localForage IndexedDB > QuotaExceededError

Tags: cordova, indexeddb, localforage

I'm developing an app with cordova (cli-8.0.0). Some data (around 3 to 7 MB) is being loaded from a server an stored in an indexedDB-database accessed via localForage.

For a couple of weeks now I'm getting an QuotaExceededError on some devices when the free storage on the user's smartphone drops below a certain amount of free space. Around 2 GB of free smartphone storage is needed right now to perform a simple setItem-Operation with localForage (tested by trying to store a simple string).

Since the space actually needed is nowhere near 2 GB, I have no idea why the operation is not successful.

I would be really thankful for any hints or ideas.

Comment: Do you solved it? I am on same problem

Comment: Not yet, but working on it... :/

Comment: Since I have not been able to solve this problem I switched over to SQLite with this plugins https://github.com/thgreasi/localForage-cordovaSQLiteDriver. Works like a charm. :)

Comment: I also turn to this solution, thanks for all.